# Why query params are disappearing from the url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

My React app is using `react-router-dom@4.3.1`.

This is how I add search after checkbox is clicked:

```
this.props.history.push({search: `?packages=${list.join(',')}`})
```

As soon as I click the checkbox, queryparam would display for a split second and disappear. UI does appear corresponding to the `queryparams`.

What could be the reason it is disappearing?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Having same issue, did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide pathname as well, path is required

Do it as this

```
this.props.history.push({pathname: '/yourpath', search: `?packages=${list.join(',')}`})
```

Hope it helps